# what is the use of QueryDefs in MSAccess (VBA)

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-2012, vba, ms-access-2010

we are using MS access as front end and Sql server as back end.I want to know the use of QueryDefs Temporary table.What is the Advantage of using QueryDefs ?

Comment: They are quite the same as views ...

Comment: Thank you..whether it is used to increase the performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of QueryDefs as being like views on a SQL server. They are a stored SQL query.  A QueryDef is a query that appears on the navigation pane under Queries.

If you are using certain types of conditional formatting in forms then the form MUST be based on a QueryDef  (eg barcharts in a control).

Instead of using a built SQL statement, by creating a querydef if can help debugging.

The performance benefits depend mainly on the structure of your SQL query, which is greatly influenced by whether you are using DAO, ADO or pass though queries to access SQL Server data and mainly on whether you use parameters (to enable the execution plan to be re-used).

General advise is to use pass through queries and leverage the use of the SQL Server stored procedures, functions and views.

Harvey

Comment: by any chance SQL query take more time to load than front end loading the same query result data?